# Swift Error: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument of list type '(String)'

Tags: swift, string

I'm just starting to learn Swift.  I watched a video on getting started with basic swift programming and I copied the instructor's code directly into my Xcode.  However, I'm getting an error in my code that he did not get in his.  I triple checked that I did everything the same.  The code is below.  The last line gives the error in the subject.

```
var items:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func additem(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (txtinput.text! == ""){
        return
    }
    items.append(txtinput.text!)
    txtoutput.text = ""
    for item in items {
        txtoutput.text.append("\(item)\n")
```

Comment: What version of Xcode and what version of Swift are you using?

Comment: and what is `txtoutput`?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `text` is of type `String`. `String` doesn't have a method called `append`. Normally you would use...

```
 txtoutput.text = txtoutput.text + "\(item)\n"    // or
 txtoutput.text += "\(item)\n"
```

However, it is also possible to write an extension, so that you can call `append`. Perhaps this is what existed in the sample you saw?

```
extension String {
    mutating func append(str: String) {
        self = self + str
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in Swift 3, `String` *does* have an [`append(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641225-append) method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the String to your existing String. 
So in your case:

```
@IBAction func additem(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (txtinput.text! == ""){
        return
    }
    items.append(txtinput.text!)
    txtoutput.text = ""   

    for item in items {
        txtoutput.text = (txtoutput.text)! + "\(item)\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: damnit... took me too long... Michael was faster :)

Comment: But an upvote for you too since the OP probably has an Optional.